# How to add custom tags in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I'm working on a WYSIWYG redactor using contenteditable and execCommand. Bold, italic an other things are working just fine, but I'm confused about how to add custom tags (e.g. "`<span style="white-space: nowrap;">`", etc.). It seems like there's no standart tools for that (which is really strange). I thought about manually manipulating DOM with code, but it seems rather hard beacuse of complex formatting, I have no idea how to make this properly (so that html will remain valid). So are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @humble.rumble http://hellosandrik.ru/temp/wysiwyg

Comment: @humble.rumble yeah, I saw that, but it clears all existing formatting within selection. Moreover, it's not even working in IE :(

Comment: Yes, it isn't easy to do "simple things" and it's complex to do things right. That's why people use othere existing editors where a team of people take care and work on all these issues instead of trying to do things again themselves.

Comment: While you say I'm reinventing the wheel, I'm in fact just trying to learn something and gain some experience. My question was about existing solutions to my problem and not about whether I should keep creating my wheel or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I stopped at this decision. It's not using insertHTML (which is not supported by IE), keeps formatting and work as expected (well, in most cases). Still searching for a better solution, but maybe it would be helpful for someone.

```
var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

var clone = $(range.cloneContents());
$.each(clone.find('.nowrap'), function(id, elem) {
    $(elem).contents().unwrap();
});

range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode($('<span class="nowrap"/>').append(clone).get(0));
```

Comment: @humble.rumble by valid HTML I meant that there won't be any unclosed and overlapping (e.g. `<b><span></b></span>`) tags. Sorry for misunderstanding. This solution deals with it (at least, I could not break it). I updated demo just in case.

Comment: @humble.rumble yes, there is no such logic, but Range methods do it for me. Maybe I'm wrong, but I was unable to get any overlapping tags so far. I'm testing in Chrome, btw. You can check it yourself at the link above ('lock' icon is running this code).